# ChildAction wants to know who is caller?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In child action method, i need to know which action method invoked before me so i can detect which action method cause to invoke me.

How can i know it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a child action simply use the `ParentActionViewContext`:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    var parentActionName = ControllerContext
        .ParentActionViewContext
        .RouteData
        .GetRequiredString("action");
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Darin, I think this is more simplified,

```
 RouteData.Route.GetRouteData(HttpContext).Values["action"]
```

Answer (score -1):

fastest is

```
StackFrame sframe = new StackFrame(1);
```

if you want full stack trace view use

```
StackTrace frame = new StackTrace();
```

Comment: :) I think it would be better to create global filter which push invoked action names.